# When I type "git commit" command , it does not open atom editor?

Tags: git, terminal, config, atom-editor

when I type git commit command in terminal it does not open atom editor , I have already done all the settings for atom editor
also it does not accept email id and password for git hub config.
the image describes the error  [image: error]

Comment: Did you run the commands suggested?

Comment: It is unrelated to your editor. You need to configure `git` appropriately.

Comment: @kryger it works.

Comment: the configuration problem is solved , but now it is showing this error :-     atom --wait: atom: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'atom --wait'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP missed or ignored instructions on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git commit is used to commit the changes we have added, for eg. with the command

```
git add --all
```

commit is then added as

```
git commit -m "this is a commit"
```

and this works fine on terminal and is enough. a text editor is not really needed
if you want to open the atom editor, i think you should explain more directly what you want to do and the reference
For adding user name and email, use

```
git config --global user.name "xyz"
git config --global user.email "xyz@a.com"
```

You need to config git for yourself that's why email and name is to be provided first